# Telling a story with traceroute: how does it work?

Tags: routes, traceroute

If you do a traceroute on [`bad.horse`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rN2U5wkhRWc) you get this amazing result:

```
⚘ traceroute bad.horse                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               10:46:24
traceroute to bad.horse (162.252.205.157), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  gateway (192.168.42.1)  0.382 ms  0.690 ms  0.795 ms
 2  10.52.192.1 (10.52.192.1)  8.594 ms  13.533 ms  14.438 ms
 3  70.183.68.108 (70.183.68.108)  14.525 ms  14.620 ms  14.643 ms
 4  70.183.71.92 (70.183.71.92)  23.323 ms  24.356 ms  24.219 ms
 5  dalsbprj01-ae1.0.rd.dl.cox.net (68.1.2.109)  119.445 ms  120.277 ms  62.337 ms
 6  10ge6-9.core1.dal1.he.net (184.105.16.77)  70.903 ms  57.131 ms  67.526 ms
 7  10ge12-6.core1.chi1.he.net (184.105.213.118)  43.732 ms  42.770 ms  43.774 ms
 8  100ge10-1.core1.msp1.he.net (184.105.223.178)  59.138 ms  60.040 ms  60.115 ms
 9  ip-house.gigabitethernet3-6.core1.msp1.he.net (216.66.78.110)  55.395 ms  54.378 ms  55.345 ms
10  c4500-1.mpls.iphouse.net (216.250.189.170)  55.412 ms  48.480 ms  53.559 ms
11  egw-iphouse.mplsc1.mn.us.sn11.net (209.240.64.149)  52.298 ms  53.225 ms  53.372 ms
12  sandwichnet.dmarc.lga1.atlanticmetro.net (208.68.168.214)  84.848 ms  83.666 ms  84.504 ms
13  bad.horse (162.252.205.130)  84.768 ms  85.393 ms  87.570 ms
14  bad.horse (162.252.205.131)  86.527 ms  90.848 ms  83.121 ms
15  bad.horse (162.252.205.132)  91.399 ms  91.158 ms  91.256 ms
16  bad.horse (162.252.205.133)  97.087 ms  96.865 ms  96.914 ms
17  he.rides.across.the.nation (162.252.205.134)  104.836 ms  104.955 ms  104.670 ms
18  the.thoroughbred.of.sin (162.252.205.135)  108.286 ms  107.884 ms  107.020 ms
19  he.got.the.application (162.252.205.136)  109.024 ms  110.304 ms  111.553 ms
20  that.you.just.sent.in (162.252.205.137)  117.034 ms  113.230 ms  115.878 ms
21  it.needs.evaluation (162.252.205.138)  123.398 ms  122.680 ms  120.805 ms
22  so.let.the.games.begin (162.252.205.139)  129.908 ms  126.529 ms  130.947 ms
23  a.heinous.crime (162.252.205.140)  131.899 ms  132.798 ms  131.009 ms
24  a.show.of.force (162.252.205.141)  136.237 ms  136.104 ms  135.543 ms
25  a.murder.would.be.nice.of.course (162.252.205.142)  140.381 ms  141.924 ms  142.517 ms
26  bad.horse (162.252.205.143)  145.723 ms  142.737 ms  148.146 ms
27  bad.horse (162.252.205.144)  152.364 ms  152.251 ms  150.875 ms
28  bad.horse (162.252.205.145)  155.535 ms  155.014 ms  152.655 ms
29  he-s.bad (162.252.205.146)  163.286 ms  161.130 ms  163.883 ms
30  the.evil.league.of.evil (162.252.205.147)  165.159 ms  167.220 ms  164.500 ms
31  is.watching.so.beware (162.252.205.148)  170.873 ms  173.487 ms  171.568 ms
32  the.grade.that.you.receive (162.252.205.149)  176.218 ms  175.204 ms  174.433 ms
33  will.be.your.last.we.swear (162.252.205.150)  182.528 ms  184.565 ms  182.459 ms
34  so.make.the.bad.horse.gleeful (162.252.205.151)  182.353 ms  187.004 ms  188.215 ms
35  or.he-ll.make.you.his.mare (162.252.205.152)  193.428 ms  190.271 ms  192.049 ms
36  o_o (162.252.205.153)  196.362 ms  196.326 ms  196.022 ms
37  you-re.saddled.up (162.252.205.154)  201.828 ms  201.184 ms  201.339 ms
38  there-s.no.recourse (162.252.205.155)  205.054 ms  207.239 ms  205.630 ms
39  it-s.hi-ho.silver (162.252.205.156)  212.140 ms  211.960 ms  212.158 ms
40  signed.bad.horse (162.252.205.157)  211.620 ms  209.723 ms  212.074 ms
```

How does that work? How do you setup a network in such a way that traceroute will give you a result like this?

Comment: You own a lot of IP addresses, assign them to routers, configure each router with a route to bad.horse via the next router in the chain, then set up reverse DNS records for each IP.

Comment: To get the whole song set the `--max-hops` option to a high number e.g. `traceroute --max-hops=60 bad.horse`

Comment: See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NgKI7-3j2hc

Comment: I guess this could be now in https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Eheheh nice!

It's because the **author of the joke owns 162.252.204.0/22** (Sandwich.Net LLC or one of their customers maybe), **consequently they have a DNS server** (162.252.205.157) that is **authoritative for all the replies to PTR queries** inside that range.

Now, they need to assign to their routers as many IPs as the number of sentences they want to show (or also assign those IPs to virtual instances inside the same physical router, or make policy routing between SVIs, etc.).

Then, they need to define an entry point (router) for the bad.horse host (162.252.205.157) in their Autonomous System AS62512 (that is, advertise 162.252.205.157 with BGP from the first router in the path).

From this entry point, they need to make a route on every other router that point to the next router till bad.horse (ie. define the path of routers that a packet entering their network with destination IP of bad.horse will follow); in other words something like:

> [Internet]-->Router0 (IP x.x.x.1)-->Router1 (IP x.x.x.2)-->Router3 (IP x.x.x.3)-->[bad.horse host]

Finally, in the DNS server, they map the IPs in the path to a string, that is the sentence you got.
From example above:

> x.x.x.1 -> hello.you
>
> x.x.x.2 -> how.are.you
>
> x.x.x.3 -> etc...

This way, when your traceroute software will receive the Time Exceed back from every router in the path (in sequence), it will try to resolve the IP to a name by reaching their DNS server, receiving the sentences (in form of DNS names) they configured.

Comment: So this joke wouldn't work without a DNS server? I didn't think it was possible to do just by owning some domain names, but that's one area that my depth of knowledge... isn't.

Comment: You don't need to own domain names actually (indeed some words used as top domains in the joke are not top domains). Basically you need to own an IP space and the related zone for the reverse DNS lookup.